# input field for amount

Tags: php, html

I'm using some payment gateway with PHP, and in there documentation:
there is an amount input which the client can put any amount of money before submitting the form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://api.linkToPaymentGateway.com/v1/payments.html" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Order id 1234 by guest" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10000" />

  <!--
  and some input's for the card information with type="text"
  -->

  <button type="submit">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

my questions:

- How to protect The amount filed and description ?
- Should i change the Action and use cURL to send the api ?

**Thank you.**

EDIT:

here is the link for doc https://moyasar.com/docs/payments/create-payment/mpf/

EDIT2:
It's an old question.

Comment: What is the actual problem ? What do mean by protect the amount field you are already using `hidden` - Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: If you don't want it on the frontend, you can do this all on the backend using curl, and have fun with the non-stop battle of keeping up with PCI Compliance... There's many CRMs out there that can do this for you and you'd have a separate product id for each such product.... if it's an issue of controlling the amount, you can leave users able to tamper with it and just check they paid the right amount once the gateway communicates back with you to decide whether to unlock whatever feature.

Comment: what i mean anyone with some knowledge of html and dev tools can change the amount field,
so i asked if there is a way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trust the hidden input of amount field from FORM. Anyone with some knowledge of html and dev tool can easily change it to any amount.

There are might be many work around to solve this. Like

1. You should send the form data to your server and calculate the amount again and call gateway apis.
2. Just trust the user here only if your api gateway has callback option. In call back you can check the amount charged and make sure that the amount is correct before updating the order.

Comment: Yes they have call back url and everything working, its just as u said anyone with some knowledge..etc. if the amount not what i expected should i void the transaction ?

Comment: That's up to you, if the amount charged is not as per your expectation. You can do whatever make send. Like is the amount charge is less then add it to your order as partial paid status or just void the order for fraud or keep the payment and block the user (please don't do it) just saying to elaborate :P

Comment: :p thinking of that thing to keep it as support from user
can u see the link, i'm not using openCart or anything 
https://moyasar.com/docs/payments/create-payment/mpf/

Thanks..

Comment: Yes, they have `Verify the payment` so verify before marking order as paid. Otherwise update the user that there are disturbances in payment or handle as your business need.

Comment: i know i took a lot of your time, i'm still thinking of a solution, should i check the payment on the server then send cURL or checking after user paid

Comment: You should call the gateway from your server (preferred) but the verify would be fine too.